# How to translate this conditional statement from Python to JS

Tags: javascript, python, conditional-statements

I'm making a little web-app based off some python code I ran a while ago, part of the python code involved this conditional statement

```
if poi in [r1.a.pos(), r1.b.pos()] and poi in [r2.a.pos(), r2.b.pos()]:
                        intersection_found = False
elif poi in [r1.a.pos(), r1.b.pos()]:
```

where poi and .pos() are tuples of the form (x, y)
I was wondering what the best way of doing this is in Javascript. Rightnow I have positions stored as an object in the form `{x: 0, y:0}`
Since you cant directly compare objects like this I was wondering how else I could do it, thank you for your help

Comment: I'd be happy to help. Can you show what the values of `poi`, `r1.a.pos()` and `r1.b.pos()` are? I'm a little rusty on my python and I want to be sure I understand properly

Comment: In python they're tuples containing two integers, such as (1, 100) or (250, 172) that represent an x, y coordinate

Comment: One possible way is to use a `class` to represent your tuple ([ES5 Class](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/class-in-javascript) vs [ES6 Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)). Then, you can add the utility methods on the prototype for do the related comparisons. For example, you could add a method for compare the tuple with a given tuple, and another one for check if a tuple belong to a given set of tuples.